# Coq ssreflect sum of sums

Tags: coq, proof, coq-tactic, ssreflect

I have been searching for a lemma in `ssreflect` that represents sum linearity, so that I could transform

```
sum(a) + sum(b) = sum(c)
```

into

```
sum(a+b) =sum(c)
```

and then derive into

```
a+b = c.
```

Which could be suitable in this case?

The goal:

```
\big[Rplus/0]_(i <- fin_img (A:=U) (B:=R_eqType) X) (.  .  .) +
\big[Rplus/0]_(i <- fin_img (A:=U) (B:=R_eqType) X) (.  .  .) =
\sum_(u in U) X u * `p_ X u
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `big_split` lemma. But it is hard to know without knowing what goal you're trying to prove in more detail...

Comment: Yes, this was the one. Thank you!

Comment: In particular that last derivation looks a big strange, there are very few cases where `sum a = sum b -> a = b`

Comment: In practice when needing a lemma about bigops, it is often necessary to go and read the lemma statements in file bigop.v  They are grouped according to the properties that are required of the binary operation.  In this case, you need this operation to be both associative and commutative.